# How to install the Early Access Build ARM img in a VM on ARM based machine?

Tags: macbook, virtualization

Is it possible to get a VM with elementaryOS 6.0 running on a ARM based machine? There is a Early Access build for ARM based computers, like the pinebook pro, but it is delivered as an .img. I was not able to create a VM out of it. Any ideas? Or does anyone know if there will be a .iso for the ARM version?

Comment: I noticed that your post is tagged as Macbook. Are you trying to test an ARM-based image in a virtual machine on an ARM-based _M1_ Macbook? And I think it would help if you elaborated on what you've tried that hasn't worked.

Comment: You can also install any debian arm distro and then add the elementary repositories. Executing `apt install elementary-desktop` will install the latest beta version of elementary available.